# Match IRC Channel with regular expression

Tags: regex, irc

How would one go about using regular expressions to match IRC channel names? The names would have the preceding hash symbol (`#`) included.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/([#&][^\x07\x2C\s]{,200})/
```

Should do it, according to [RFC<sup>1459</sup>](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/chapter1.html#c1_3)'s specification.

Comment: @DeaDEnD: Indeed, some regex may be picky and want it explicit. But you're right, the `{,200}` is essentially `{0,200}`.

Comment: This should actually be `{,199}`. According to RFC 1459, "Channels names are strings (beginning with a '&' or '#' character) of length up to 200 characters", which includes the leading `#` symbol, so the trailing characters in the name are just 199 at most.