# Grabbing an IRC channel in a string with regex

Tags: java, regex

This is my first time posting here, but I've found a lot of answers here, which is awesome.

I'm currently trying to grab an IRC channel from a string, and the IRC channel prefix is (#), which means that the channel would be something like:

- ## channel
- ## another_channel
- ## yet-another_channel

Channels don't have spaces, so if it was (#a channel), the channel would just be (#a).

I'm trying to parse that sort of like I parsed my URLs, which is like so:

```
public String[] splitString(String string) {
    String pattern = "(?i)(http(s?)://|www\\.)\\S++";
    String[] split = string.split(String.format("((?<=%s)\\s++)|(\\s++(?=%s))", pattern, pattern));
    return split;
}
```

Leaving me with a result that would split a String in a way that there is separate parts.  An example of how it works is:

```
String test = "let's see how this http://google.com/ thing works, www.shall.we";
Result: ["let's see how this", "http://google.com/", "thing works, ", "www.shall.we"]
```

I hope that makes sense.

All in all, I guess I'm just looking for some regex to get an IRC channel from a string.

I've found this [Match IRC Channel with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953301/match-irc-channel-with-regular-expression) but it doesn't seem to work how I'm looking for it to work.

Comment: Does this have to use regex? I can think of a way of doing this without regex.

Comment: *"I've found a lot of answers here, which is awesome."* You might have noticed that a lost of those threads with answers, also had a question.  What is your question?

Comment: No, I don't _have_ to use regex, I just couldn't think of any other way to do it and this seemed to be the most common way.

Comment: @Andrew _All in all, I guess I'm just looking for some regex to get an IRC channel from a string._  I guess that I could've been more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex to do this for your simple definition would be

```
(#\S+)
```

which means a `#` followed by at least one character that is not a whitespace. If you want, you can narrow the allowed characters by choosing another [character class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) like `\w` to allow only letters and digits.

Comment: Does this support any characters afterwards? Such as #a-test or #a_test?

Comment: That depends on your character group. `\S` supports it, since neither `-` nor `_` are whitespaces. But it also allows other characters that are not a letter or digit. You can specify exactly what is allowed by spelling it out. So `[\w-]` will allow letters, digits, `_` and `-`. You can also spell it out completely to read `[a-zA-Z_0-9-]`. See the character class link from the answer for more information.