# Match IRC channel with regular expression (RFCs 2811-2813)

Tags: regex, irc, rfc

I know this question has been [answered in accordance with RFC 1459](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953301/match-irc-channel-with-regular-expression). But how would one go about using regular expressions to match channels in accordance with RFCs 2811-2813?

RFC 2811 states:

> Channels names are strings (beginning with a '&', '#', '+' or '!'
>   character) of length up to fifty (50) characters.  Channel names are
>   case insensitive.
>
> Apart from the the requirement that the first character being either
>   '&', '#', '+' or '!' (hereafter called "channel prefix"). The only
>   restriction on a channel name is that it SHALL NOT contain any spaces
>   (' '), a control G (^G or ASCII 7), a comma (',' which is used as a
>   list item separator by the protocol).  Also, a colon (':') is used as
>   a delimiter for the channel mask.  The exact syntax of a channel name
>   is defined in "IRC Server Protocol" [IRC-SERVER].

And supplementing that, RFC 2812 states:

> ```
> channel    =  ( "#" / "+" / ( "!" channelid ) / "&" ) chanstring
>               [ ":" chanstring ]
> chanstring =  %x01-07 / %x08-09 / %x0B-0C / %x0E-1F / %x21-2B
> chanstring =/ %x2D-39 / %x3B-FF
>                 ; any octet except NUL, BELL, CR, LF, " ", "," and ":"
> channelid  = 5( %x41-5A / digit )   ; 5( A-Z / 0-9 )
> ```

Comment: So given the answer `/([#&][^\x07\x2C\s]{,200})/` (from your linked question), how would you modify it to match your new specification?

Comment: @GregHewgill That is correct. The part that really confuses me is the `channelid` stuck right in the middle.

Comment: Thanks, that helps clarify what you're really asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show you how to create a composite regex, I'll make a simplified example.

Suppose a channel name can be up to 20 characters, with lowercase letters only. A regex matching this might be:

```
[#&][a-z]{1,20}
```

That is, a `#` or `&`, followed by 1 to 20 letters. Since the channelid doesn't follow the same pattern, a regex for that might be:

```
![A-Z0-9]{5}
```

which is a `!` followed by exactly 5 uppercase letters or digits. For a complete regex that matches either of these, you combine them with `(...|...)`, like this:

```
([#&][a-z]{1,20}|![A-Z0-9]{5})
```

You can then drop in your slightly more complex regex for the exact channel name pattern you want to match.

Comment: So, for example, I'd write something along the lines of `([#&+][A-Za-z0-9]{1,49}|![A-Z0-5]{5}[A-Za-z0-9]{1,44})` to match only alphanumeric channels of up to length 50 (using RFC)?

Answer (score 0):

As defined by the RFC2812 (if i'm not mistaken) except it does not handle the max length (50 bytes),
it's a python regexp, it's quickly made, but should work properly... :

```
^(((![A-Z0-9]{5})|([#+&][^\x00\x07\r\n ,:]+))(:[^\x00\x07\r\n ,:]+)?)$
```

you can visualize the regexp logic [here](http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%28%28%28!%5BA-Z0-9%5D%7B5%7D%29%7C%28%5B#+&%5D%5B%5E%5Cx00%5Cx07%5Cr%5Cn%20,:%5D+%29%29%28:%5B%5E%5Cx00%5Cx07%5Cr%5Cn%20,:%5D+%29?%29$)

HTH..